# HTML5 markup for jQuery UI accordion

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have the following markup and I want to use the jQuery UI accordion, but it is not rendered like the typical accordion I have made before HTML5. How could I get the accordion by using article/section?

```
<article>
    <h1>Accordion</h1>
    <div id="accordion">
        <section>
            <h1><a href="#">Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</a></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna.</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h1><a href="#">Integer vitae libero ac risus egestas placerat.</a></h1>
            <p>Sed egestas, ante et vulputate volutpat, eros pede semper est, vitae luctus metus libero eu augue. Morbi purus libero, faucibus adipiscing, commodo quis, gravida id, est. Sed lectus.</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h1><a href="#">Fusce lobortis lorem at ipsum semper sagittis.</a></h1>
            <p>Morbi interdum mollis sapien. Sed ac risus. Phasellus lacinia, magna a ullamcorper laoreet, lectus arcu pulvinar risus, vitae facilisis libero dolor a purus. Sed vel lacus.</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</article>
```

In javascript I use:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#accordion').accordion();    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a side note, you'd be better off using the [`details` and `summary`](http://html5doctor.com/the-details-and-summary-elements/) elements.

Comment: I have seen an example that uses the jQuery UI Accordion with those elements and that really works. However, could it be possible to make it works by using the section/article elements?

Comment: You can use whatever elements you like really, but details and summary are more semantic for this in my view.

Comment: excellent suggestion, but currently browser support is limited... http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_summary.asp

Answer (score 3):

We have tested the following code in JSFiddle...

```
<div id="accordion">
   <article class="std_page_content">
    <a id="#test" href="#test" class="header"><h1>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus</h1></a>
    <section>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna.</p>
        </section>
    <a href="#test" class="header"><h1>Integer vitae libero ac risus egestas placerat.</h1></a>
       <section>
            <p>Sed egestas, ante et vulputate volutpat, eros pede semper est, vitae luctus metus libero eu augue. Morbi purus libero, faucibus adipiscing, commodo quis, gravida id, est. Sed lectus.</p>
        </section>
       <a href="#test" class="header"><h1>Fusce lobortis lorem at ipsum semper sagittis.</h1></a>
        <section>
            <p>Morbi interdum mollis sapien. Sed ac risus. Phasellus lacinia, magna a ullamcorper laoreet, lectus arcu pulvinar risus, vitae facilisis libero dolor a purus. Sed vel lacus.</p>
        </section>
   </article>
</div>
```

and the accordion code  as -

```
$("#accordion").accordion({header : "a.header", heightStyle : "content", 
   /*Allows full collapse*/collapsible: true, 
   /*collapses sections*/ active:false, 
   navigation:true
});
```

Our link is - http://jsfiddle.net/3tGYB/2/

You can try this one...

Comment: I really appreciate your answer!! However in HTML5 the section element should have the h1-6 heading elements inside (see HTML5 Document Outlines and Section: http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/)

Comment: @Rowgm I have gone through your link. Thanks for pointing us this. Also here you can put HI tag inside section. But as per Jquery Accordion UI we have to put some element as header and then a section of content. So in href tag you can put some other content as per requirement. Also you can go through http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ for the source documentation. Thanks again for pointing...